# is there a better PROCESS for picking office printers?

Tags: drivers, network-printer, imaging, hardware

I run a small Mac/Linux/Android network and finding options for our new printer has been difficult. We have a few criteria, and as you all know, the market is pretty convoluted, with long feature lists and rapid model turnover.

Looking for intersections between the lists of models that "work perfectly" on [openprinting.org](http://openprinting.org), lists of models i can find for sale online, and the lists of models on each manufacturer's site which have enough of the features we want, then filtering on whether that model seems to require closed-source binary drivers or if I can find a PPD file, is tedious. The driver situation seems to be all over the place and "Linux support" a nearly meaningless term. Since all the lists are mostly dead ends with regards to each other, this is really slow going.

Am I missing any important resource or does anyone have a superior process or rule of thumb to use for a hardware purchase like this? Just for completeness, not because I expect printer recommendations, our particular search is for a black, all-in-one monochrome laser with 802.11.

Comment: Pick something that supports raw postscript. Purchase it from a place with a reasonable return policy. If it doesn't work, return it and try something else.

Comment: Alternatively, enlist a local printer rental shop. Tell them your requirements and let them deal with the details. That's what I do - they take care of all printer maintenance, toner refills, trouble calls, etc. I get to blissfully wash my hands of any printer support issues. :)

Comment: I'm tempted to dv this just because it's about printers, which are my nemesis. :)

Comment: I was promised a paperless office! What happened to the paperless office?

Comment: The suppliers took it back when we couldn't print out, sign, and return the acceptance form.